# How to validate if an element exists and invoke send_keys method through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

This is my HTML code. When I click on one button, the page shows me a div with this code:

```html
<label for="email"> "Add an email address"
    <input name="email" id="email" class="mb3 ember-text-field ember-view"type="email">
</label>
```

First thing I want to do is to check if I have `<input>`. If yes, I want to do the `send_keys()`.

I tried something like this:

```
buttons = (driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".button-secondary-medium"))
for i in range(len(buttons)):
    buttons[i].click()
    y = randint(5, 9)
    time.sleep(y)
try:
    email = ui.WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email")))
    email.send_keys(" paul@yahoo.com")
except:
    print("no input")
```

I have a list of buttons, each button shows me a blank `div` and sometimes the 
button shows a div with an input email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".button-secondary-medium")

for button in buttons:

    button.click()

    try:

        email = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email")))
        email.send_keys("paul@yahoo.com")

    except:

        print("There is no input element.")
```

I used here explicit wait and 10-second wait for the element to be clickable and intractable. The `try/except` block is used for checking that `input` exists.

PS: Also, I don't understand the usage of the plural version of `find_element_*`, because you have only one `input` element in your HTML code.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: @PaulVio, I have updated my answer. Check it, please, again. Thanks.

Comment: Why you can't call? I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: email.send_keys(" ") doesn't work. for email works only `email.if email.ifn email.main etc`

Comment: @PaulVio, post your full code in question (update it).

Comment: Done, do you get it? When the `buttons[i].click` shows me the `div` with `input` i want to send the email there

Comment: I have one more question, I have two types of buttons, with the same classes, ids etc, but two things are different. The action they do, and the text. One has "invite" text, the other one "message". I want to do something when it's "invite" and something else when it's "message". Do you know if I have to use an if or something?

Comment: Yes, you can use `if`, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for the *input* tag and invoke `send_keys()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* within a `try-catch{}` block for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='email']"))).send_keys("Paul@Vio.com")
  except TimeoutException:
      print("Element doesn't exist")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```